# Box2d Loop Shape / create static ground shape in Cocos2D

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

Does anyone know what is the best method to create a static ground body with many (~10000) vertices in Box2D (the version that comes with Cocos2D).

This is what I do now for cubic beziers, it looks fine but runs a bit slow.

```
for (int i = 0; i<segments; i++) {
    CGPoint p2 = vertices[i+1];
    CGPoint p1 = vertices[i];
    b2PolygonShape poly;
    poly.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(p1.x,p1.y), b2Vec2(p2.x, p2.y));
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&poly,0);
}
```

People talk about b2LoopShape but it doesn't seem like it's included in the Box2d version shipped with Cocos?

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Erik. I can imagine that many vertices will slow things down. Why do you need that many? Perhaps there are other options. b2LoopShape isn't included with cocos2d. I am not familiar with it, so I don't know how much work it would be to port that.

Comment: Hi Nash! It actually runs fine now, even on my iphone 3, but I didn't go for 10000 vertices, i got it down to ~2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For b2LoopShape, you need to replace external/Box2d with Box2D trunk.

1. checkout Box2D trunk from [box2d](http://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/checkout).
2. replace cocos2d/external/Box2d with trunk/Box2D/Box2D.
3. modify Xcode project for added Box2D files.
4. modify some codes for renamed classes such as s/b2DebugDraw/b2Draw/.